# Does (type)(math expression) evaluates the expression to this type?

Tags: c++, expression

Recently, I was dealing with a problem in competitive programming, and changing `(long long)(n*(n-1))/2` to `(long long)n*(n-1)/2` made a difference, these things are not the same ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau why ?

Comment: If `n=1000000`, first expression may return wrong result because `n*(n-1)` will exceed 32 bit int, when second should work.

Comment: but why ? I thought that long long would evaluate the whole expression (n*(n-1))/2

Comment: @WeslleyMatheus See the answer I just posted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So i.e : the variable x, in (type)x*(blablabla + x * blabla..), will be the only variable casted to long long?

Comment: @WeslleyMatheus yes, and only the first instance of `x` right next to `(type)`, not the `x` in `... + x * ...`. If you want the result of the whole expression casted, you need extra parenthesis around the whole expression: `(type)(x*(blablabla + x * blabla..))` or `type(x*(blablabla + x * blabla..))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

According to [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), type casts have a higher precedence than arithmetic operations.

As such, the expression:

`(long long)(n*(n-1))/2`

is evaluated by the compiler *as if* it had been written like this instead:

`(((long long)(n*(n-1)))/2)`

ie, the whole expression `n*(n-1)` is inside of its own set of parenthesis, so it is evaluated first, then its result is casted to `long long`, then that result is divided by `2`.

And the expression:

`(long long)n*(n-1)/2`

is evaluated by the compiler *as if* it had been written like this instead:

`((((long long)n)*(n-1))/2)`

ie, `n` is not inside of parenthesis so it gets casted by itself to `long long` first, then that result is multiplied by `(n-1)`, and then that result is divided by `2`.

When in doubt of which expression gets evaluated before another expression, you should use explicit parenthesis to take control over which operations you want to perform in which order.

Comment: I never get this 'add in the "missing" parentheses' stuff, which is all your examples seem to be doing. They change *nothing.* The point is really whether the expression gets evaluated before the cast, as in your first exmaples, or whether `n` gets cast first, which changes the precision to which the rest of the expression is evaluated.